# VBA - select the first file from a specific folder and reply all

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I saved multiple outlook msg on a specific folder named "email temp folder" and would to reply on the first msg in the folder.

However there is an error: type mismatch occur in the below lines.

Could you somebody help me on this please?

```
Sub outlookActivate1()

  Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
  Dim objFolder As Object
  Dim objFile As Object
  Dim FileItemToUse As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim i As Long

  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  strPath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\email temp folder" & "\"
  strFiles = Dir(strPath & "*.*")
  Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

  For Each objFile In objFolder.Files 

    If i = 0 Then    
      Set FileItemToUse = objFile     // error: type mismatch       
    End If

  Next objFile


  With FileItemToUse

    .ReplyAll
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Hi"
    .HTMLBody = "testing"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .display

  End With

  Set OutMail = Nothing
  Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate of **over 800** questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bvba%5d%20type%20mismatch).

Answer (score 0):

It means that `objFile` is not of type `Outlook.MailItem` as you declared on top of your code.

Relying on the fact that your email template will always be the first item in the `Files` collection of the folder is not really stable, as the file might change position (probably is already not there, since you get the `type mismatch` error - you're probably trying to cast another type into a variable that is supposed to be a `Outlook.MailItem` type).

My suggestion is to reference directly to the file object; which means, in your code:

```
Set objFile = fso.GetFile("C:\...\mytemplate.msg")
```

and keep on running the code without the need to neither `getFolder()` nor looping `For Each objFile` in the `Files` collection, hoping that your file will be the first one.

However, best way to understand these kind of errors is to run the code in debug mode (press `F8` and run line by line) and, by adding some watchers, figuring out what is what at run-time.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I still want to put 1 file at a time in the folder. So is it possible to parse FileItemToUse into an outlook item?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry. Could you please give me some more context?

Comment: Instead of looping through multiple files in "email temp folder". I will just put 1 file in the folder (FileItemToUse)  and reply on top of it. In my code, I set FileItemToUse = objFile but its not working because they are 2 different types. So how am i able to fix it?

Comment: I don't know the type of your object, you should know it. You can use the function `TypeName(objFile)` to figure it out and then declare your `FileItemToUse` consequently.

Comment: objFile is object and FileItemToUse is Outlook.MailItem. If i dim FileItemToUse as object, it will match objFile but there would be error from .replyAll as it is not an outlook item.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any direct methods for opening .msg files on the disk. However, you can use the following workarounds to get the job done:

1. The [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865637.aspx) method of the Application class which allows to create a new Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) or just a message file (.msg) and returns the new item. See [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) for more information.
2. Use the ShellExecute method to open the file programmatically. Be aware, only one instance of the Outlook Application can be run at the same time. Thus, the message file will be opened in a new inspector window.

   `Sub CreateFromTemplate() 
      Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
      Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("D:\message.msg") 
      MyItem.Display 
    End Sub`